# Named function vs assigned anonymous function in Redux Action Creators

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux

I have tried researching this but was rather swamped, was wondering if someone has a solid answer regarding use of named functions in redux action creators vs named functions - is there any performance difference? Or any other factors that affect this?

eg:

```
function getUserIdentity() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.GET_USER_IDENTITY,
    });
  }
}
```

vs

```
const getUserIdentity = () => (dispatch) => { dispatch({type: types.GET_USER_IDENTITY}) };
```

Thanks!

Comment: First one is es5 and second is es6. Performance won't be different but its better to use es6 over es5.

Comment: @Fawaz No and no.

Comment: Agree with @Fawaz, choose arrow functions over the old, clunky way.

Answer (score 1):

Any performance difference doesn't matter, the two functions aren't even doing the same. The arrow function "equivalent" of your function declaration would be

```
const getUserIdentity = () => (dispatch) => { dispatch({type: types.GET_USER_IDENTITY}) };
```

not

```
const getUserIdentity = (dispatch) => dispatch({ type: types.GET_USER_IDENTITY });
```

as in your question.

---

Regarding the updated question, no there is no performance difference between calling the different function types. However, there is still a behavioural difference, see [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572) and also [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) - a variable initialisation happens at a different time than that of a "hoisted" function declaration, which might make a difference depending on how/where the function is used.

Comment: @bergi Question was about function style for **action creators** however, where none of this makes any difference.

Comment: Action creators were only an example of context - was just curious generally!

Comment: @timotgl Yes, none of this makes a difference, that's why there is no difference in performance either.

Comment: @timotgl However, aren't action creators typically `export`ed from ES6 modules? In that case, hoisting could make a difference.